# Statistics for the number of empty vessels for large systems

Tags: probability, combinatorics, variance

Consider randomly (iid) dropping $b$ balls into $n$ vessels. I am interested in the statistics of $e$, the number of empty vessels. I've seen elsewhere on stackexchange that this can be written down in terms of Stirling numbers of the second kind, but I don't have a good sense of how to extract useful information from those expressions. I'm most interested in the following information:

1. Can we find the probability distribution for $e$ in the large-$n$ limit, at least in some regimes for $k$? Can we say that the empty fraction $e/n$ is a function of the average number of balls per vessel $b/n$ in this limit?
2. Can we find the mean and variance of $e$, again in the large-system limit?

I've tried a few things already. I started off by simply calculating the odds that no balls fell within $e$ specific vessels and then the odds that none fell within $e+1$ specific vessels. But of course it's wrong to say that the difference between these two numbers is proportional to the probability of exactly $e$ empty vessels.

Next, I tried to write down a recursion relationship, in which $P(e,b+1)$, the probability of $e$ empties given $b+1$ balls is (Edited to fix error)

$$P(e,b+1) = P(e,b)(1-e/n) + P(e+1,b)((e+1)/n).$$

That one still seems to me to be correct, and I wanted to rewrite it in terms of $b/n$ and $e/n$ and then do a Taylor expansion. That gives me a PDE, but when I try to solve it I get nonsensical answers.

Comment: Sorry @Somos I screwed up when I tried to relabel it from empty to full vessels. The probability of $e$ empties in one step should be the probability that you had $e$ empties in the preceding step and then a ball went into a full vessel plus the probability that you had $e+1$ empties in the preceding step and then hit an empty vessel. I wrote $e-1$ instead of $e+1$ because I was thinking of how it worked when I was writing things in terms of full vessels rather than empty ones.

Comment: @Somos Arg, darnit, you're right, thanks. I should have just left it in terms of the full vessels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unsure if a simple expression exists for the full probability distribution but the mean is approximately
$$
n e^{-b/n}:=ne^{-\lambda}
$$
and the variance is approximately
$$
n(e^{-\lambda}-(1+\lambda)e^{-2\lambda} )
$$
for $b/n:=\lambda$ small enough. This is the Poisson heuristic.

**Edit:** The basic idea is the following, you can adapt to your choice of $b.$

Let $Z$ be the number of empty vessels.  We can write $Z = \sum_{i=1}^n E_i$ where $E_i$ is $1$ if vessel number $i$ is empty, $0$ otherwise.

$\mathbb{E}(E_i)$ is the probability that vessel number $i$ is empty, namely $(1 - 1/n)^b$, so $E(Z) = n (1 - 1/n)^b$.

For two distinct vessels $i$ and $j$, $\mathbb{E}(E_i E_j)$ is the probability that both are empty, namely
$(1 - 2/n)^b$.   There are $b(b-1)$ such ordered pairs.  On the other hand
$\mathbb{E}(E_j^2) = \mathbb{E}(E_j) = (1 - 1/n)^b$, and there are $n$ of these.  So
$\mathbb{E}(Z^2) = n(n-1) (1 - 2/n)^b + n (1 - 1/n)^b$, and
$$\mathbb{Var}(Z) = \mathbb{E}(Z^2) - \mathbb{E}(Z)^2 = n(n-1)(1 - 2/n)^b + n (1 - 1/n)^b - n^2 (1 - 1/n)^{2b}.$$

References (you can find the Raab paper online):

1. Raab, Martin; Steger, Angelika (1998). Luby, Michael; Rolim, José D. P.; Serna, Maria (eds.). ""Balls into Bins" — A Simple and Tight Analysis". Randomization and Approximation Techniques in Computer Science. Lecture Notes in Computer Science. Berlin, Heidelberg: Springer: 159–170.
2. Kotz, Samuel; Johnson, Norman Lloyd (1977). Urn models and their applications. New York, NY: John Wiley & Sons.

Comment: This approximation agrees with some of my simulations. Any reference?

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful! I'm also interested in $b\sim1$ and $b \gg 1$, though.

Comment: Great, thanks @kodlu Since I'm interested in the large system limit, I take the results you found for mean and variance and define $c\equiv b/n$ and consider the limit where $n$ grows large and $c$ remains finite. When I do, I find (could still have some dumb errors) a mean of about $n e^{-c}$ and a variance of about $n(e^{-c}-(1+c)e^{-2 c})$

Comment: Yes, that's correct